# C++Rest SDK Passing a long data type into request body results in 400 Bad Request

Tags: c++, json, casablanca

My Swagger document defines a long data type expected to be sent in request like:

```
    size:
      type: integer
      format: int64
      description: 'Some size'
```

I create request using following code in C++:

```
web::json::value postData = web::json::value::object();
```

If I pass a hardcoded value (i.e 50 or so) in the body as below, I get 200 OK response, so that is good

```
postData[L"size"] = web::json::value::number(50);
```

However, if I pass this value as a long or int64_t data type variable like below, I get 400 Bad Request

```
long size = 50;   //or int64_t, it results with same error
postData[L"size"] = web::json::value::number(size);
```

Comment: Do you not have a way to see the messages that are sent to see what the difference is?

Comment: Looking at the source for json::value, it only accepts double, int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, and uint64_t so passing in a long or a hardcoded value would run the same function  So I'm not sure that is the problem.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks for your reply.  I have tried both long and int64_t variable type and in both cases I get 400 response.  If I pass just hardcoded number like 50, I get 200 response.  My initial question contained some confusing comments, so I updated it to be clear, sorry about that and thanks.  And to answer your question, no I dont have a way to look at the sent message to see what is the diference?  I use PostMan but that way, the values are hardcoded, I have no way to pass in actual variable like from C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I use MockLabs to create mock calls.
So, in there I had POST request body defined to be like:

```
{ "size":1 }
```

So, if my incoming POST request had a value different than 1 (i.e 50), I would get 400 Bad Request; otherwise, I would get 200 OK.  If you keep this POST request body, then you can only send size=1, all other will return 400 Bad Request.

Since I was hardcoding 1, I was getting 200 OK
But when I used a variable in my code (which is different than 1), I would get 400 Bad Request.

The solution:
Simply remove POST request body definition in your mock server (I use MockLabs) and leave it blank.  Then it will accept any POST request with body (i.e `{ "size":1 }` or `{ "size":450 }`, or `{ "size":8 }`, or whatever other integer you want) and will response with 200 OK.